# How do I change my desktop folders from having addition characters per line?

Tags: macos, mac, desktop, macbook-pro, osx-el-capitan

A few weeks ago I had an issue with copying a folder to my external hard drive, and I solved it by deleting this file with `desktop.plist` at the end of the file name.

It solved my problem, but now on my desktop there are additional characters per line, so if folders are close together the text of the folder names will overlap (*as shown in the image linked*).

Desktop folders text overlap problem

[image: Desktop folders text overlap problem]

I have tried changing all the desktop settings and deleting that desktop.plist file again, but to no success.

How can I fix this?

Comment: When you close out of all finder programs and select **View** then click **Show View Options** is there Grid Spacing? have you played with that?